# Does the same fighting style stack with itself?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, stacking, fighting-style

Suppose I have a ranger with the style Archery, and I take a one level dip into fighter and also pick Archery. Do I get an additional +4 to my attack rolls, or just +2? More generally, does the same Fighting Style stack with itself in other cases, like dueling with Paladin and dueling with Fighter?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Everywhere that you can get a Fighting Style includes this important sentence:

> You can’t take a
>   Fighting Style option more than once, even if you later
>   get to choose again.

So it doesn't matter whether it stacks with itself, because you can never take it twice.